# How to find detailed information about FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi XE4 Enterprise. How do I find out if I have FireMonkey or FM2 or FM3?

Where does Embarcadero store the detailed information about FireMonkey versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, the list of FireMonkey versions, and associated Delphi versions is:

- **FM1:** Delphi XE2
- **FM2:** Delphi XE3
- **FM3:** Delphi XE4/5

The FireMonkey version is more of a marketing designation than a true software version. Principally it's Delphi itself that is versioned.

It's a little debateable as to what FireMonkey version ships with XE5. Following the pattern, it ought to be FM4. But I can find no reference anywhere to Embarcadero using the name FM4. So I rather suspect that this is what happened (all speculation on my part):

- The original release with XE2 was named plain FireMonkey.
- The release with XE3 removed iOS support and fixed many deep and fundamental flaws with breaking changes So it was branded FM2.
- With XE4, iOS returned and more flaws were fixed, again with breaking changes. The library was reaching stability, and named FM3. They even used FM<sup>3</sup> in marketing material. Exponentially better than the original was perhaps the message. Or is that just the mathematician in me? Maybe the marketing people thought it looked cool.
- XE5 added Android support and had some more, albeit more minor, breaking changes. Somebody at Embarcadero said, if we keep changing FM version then people will get fed up with all our breaking changes. So let's just call the thing FireMonkey and leave it at that.

Going forward I think you'll just see FireMonkey and FM from Embarcadero. The version that counts is the Delphi version.

Comment: I would say, XE5 has FM3.1 or FM3vXE5, because there are some code breaking changes from XE4 to XE5 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Refactoring_in_XE5

Comment: +1 for that marketing aspect. AFAIK noone ever asked about the VCL version number. Both are not sold seperately, so there is no technical need of such an extra version number :o)

Comment: Probably `FireMonkeyVersion` is intended to hold software version. Judging by the value, it seems to be derived from product version and fm update.

Comment: I see some evidence that the breaking changes are due to a recognition that the original approach was broken and needed a break. This has not happened as much in Delphi VCL, as in FMX.  FireMonkey/FMX has had a few "course corrections" and these are the reason for the "generation" numbers.  One has to do some rework each time in any medium/large app.

Comment: According to the FMX.Styles unit in XE5 the current version of a style file is 2.5, although the comment for the FireMonkey25StyleSign constant claims it's V3.0.

Answer (score 2):

The version of the FMX framework depends on the Delphi compiler version you use.

Until now, each Delphi version (starting from XE2) contains a somehow different/extended/changed Firemonkey framework.

BTW Delphi XE4 Firemonkey framework is FM3